# Resx tools for asp site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, localization, resx

i am coding a pretty large intranet based web system that needs to support multi language. i have in excess of 150 pages, each of which will have an associated resx file. developing in vs2008

at the moment the hurdles i'm facing.

1. the sheer volume. opening each page, going to design view and clicking generate local resource is a nightmare but one that is being coped with.
2. creating a file for each of the languages i'm supporting means creating a copy of the default resx file and renaming it for each language (file name) and then opening each file and upating each key individually in vs2008.
3. for datagrids, vs doesn't pick up headertext attribute for boundcolumns. at the moment i am adding these manually to the resx file after generating. the bigger issue with this is that if for whatever reason i need to regenerate the resx for this page, vs eats up the manually added keys (for the headertexts) and i need to add them again manually.

my question is twofold:

1. are there any tools (preferably free) to assist with any or all of the above issues.
2. are there any tricks of the trade in vs2008 to ease the pain of all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resource Refactoring Tool**
[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ResourceRefactoring&DownloadId=3748](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ResourceRefactoring&DownloadId=3748)

Microsoft "open source" Visual Studio tool that integrates with the IDE. You can easily replace every occurrence of a string with a resource reference with a few clicks.
http://www.codeplex.com/ResourceRefactoring

**Zeta Resource Editor**
[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ZetaResourceEditor&DownloadId=40997](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ZetaResourceEditor&DownloadId=40997)

A side by side editor for multiple resource file.
http://www.codeplex.com/ZetaResourceEditor/

Comment: Hi Eduardo. thanks for the feedback. yes, we had already come across zeta and found it pretty useful, other than the fact that we still need to create the resx pages FIRST manually. but once that task is done, i foresee us using this exclusively. will spend this morning checking out the resource refactoring tool.

Comment: Hi again. ok i've fooled around a little and i'm having some issues. i've downloaded RRT and it installed fine. when i right click, the right menus pop up and the RRT interface pops up. for a web application, it saves the resource file but refuses to display in the select area. no matter where i save the resx file. out of curiousity i tried it with a console app and it worked perfectly. created the resx file. i have access to it in the drop down in the interface, and it updates the files correctly. just doesn't work at all for asp.net and vb backend. any ideas?

Comment: I have always used Global Resources, partitioned into several resources if the project is big. I have Zeta opened side by side with VS when the project needs to be localized.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, just some feedback. although the RRT didn't work in the asp side of the application, it definitely saved us a couple days of mindless labour on the backend. the sad thing is that RRT seems like a pretty useful app so it's actually really disappointing that the developers who made it haven't updated it. from the small bugs reported as well as the tons of requests. but thanks for your help. saved lives :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the [WestWindWebToolkit](http://www.west-wind.com/WestWindWebToolkit/) which contains a tool to manage resources and the resources are stored in the database instead of resx files which might be a maintanance plus for you.

Comment: This actually looks like it will help in a lot of useful areas. will have a look at it, but already cringing at the price tag :). thanks